# Why is ASCII encoding set as default on my Django2.0 project? How to change it?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, ascii

After pushing to a server, my Django application started to raise UnicodeEncodeError in various locations of the code (e.g. in printing, handling request in views):

```
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
> 165-168: ordinal not in range(128)
```

ASCII codec? I use Django2.0 and Python 3.6, which both use UTF-8 as default.
Also, for configuration I still use SQLite, which always utilizes UTF-8 for internal encoding, so it’s not an issue with database.
I don’t have any additional settings for encoding (I use things like `LANGUAGE_CODE`,  `USE_I18N`, `USE_L10N`, but I don’t see how this could be relevant), especially I didn’t set `DEFAULT_CHARSET` or `LC_CTYPE`.

On my local machine my application runs fine, so I checked an environment bin/activate file on the server, but found nothing suspicious there.

I even tried to set the encoding explicitly by adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top, but without noticeable effect.

What could be source of this problem? What settings on server order application to try to encode non-ascii characters with an ASCII codec? How to change it?

Comment: make sure your server is configured to use python 3. It may be happening that your install script has python 2 mentioned in it, and that is what is getting installed on server.

Comment: Hmmm, but Django2.0 doesn't even work with Python 2. The Python version installed on the server is 3.6.4

Comment: was there ever an upgrade from python 2 to python 3 for this project? there are reported instances when upgrading to python 3 caused unicodedecodeerror.

Comment: Not really. The project on the server was always python3, but parts of code were taken from python3 app, which once was python2. How can I test, whether this is the source of the problem?

Comment: In Python 3, UTF-8 is the default for source code encoding (so you don't need the source-code declaration) and for `str.encode/decode`. But the default for `open`ing files and reading/writing from/to the std channels is platform/locale dependent.

Comment: That's probably it. I bet the loggs are in ascii only. I'll try it and let you know of the results.